# Why are only five migration SE sites offered when close flagging a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I just saw this question, and wanted to flag it for closing. So I went through the assistant and thought that this question may fit into another StackExchange site (e.g. life hacks, etiquette etc.). But the only sites offered were these:

[image: migration options]

Why do you only offer these five sites? I mean, the StackExchange network has 120 Q&A sites, so why are here only five offered? Shouldn't there be a search field where you can search for the appropriate site?

## Update

There have already been comments and answers that answer my question. To keep the discussion flowing: Shouldn't there be a sixth option that says: "None of the listed migration path apply, let moderator chose where to migrate to"?

Comment: That question shouldn't be migrated, it's spam. To answer your question: [What is the reasoning behind restricting the number of migration paths?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203318/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-restricting-the-number-of-migration-paths)

Comment: You're right about that. I'm asking in general, not related to the question. I'm going to delete the picture in order to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Detailed answers are available on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203318/167646), but essentially:

> Most users don't know enough about the target site to judge whether a question is suitable or not. Limiting the number of migration paths to a handful of sites that have an established history of successful migrations (by mods) reduces the number of bad migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Form should then include any workaround to propose another site.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel - I refer you to my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230853/migrating-to-something-not-in-the-list/230854#230854).

Comment: Then wouldn't it be a good idea to enable this feature for more experienced users (depending on the reputation)?

Comment: When a questions is tagged as `Emacs` the https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ could be offered in that case. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417330/4865723