# Add sites we're member to the list of sites for migration

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

I understand the reason ([see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253998/why-are-only-five-migration-se-sites-offered-when-close-flagging-a-question) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203318/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-restricting-the-number-of-migration-paths) posts) the list of proposed sites for migration is limited to a small amount of selected sites (even if I'm little bit surprised TeX is one of them).

> Most users don't know enough about the target site to judge whether a question is suitable or not. Limiting the number of migration paths to a handful of sites that have an established history of successful migrations (by mods) reduces the number of bad migrations.

I completely agree with this but then **list may be filled ALSO with sites we're members**. In theory we should know them enough to propose a migration. List itself may be limited to sites where our **rep is higher than a threshold** (to pick a number I'd say 150: 100 bonus and 50 of true activity). Threshold may be even much higher (let's say 1000) because absence of this feature won't limit existing users (it'll just help some of them, like the immediate close for duplicates when voter has gold badge on one tag).

This will greatly simplify our reviews of Close Votes queue, it's a little help but reviews are always boring and to make them simpler can be an advantage (encouraging to do it more often).

Comment: You can be a member of the site with very little rep, that doesn't mean you know what is on-topic for it.  What threshold do you think is appropriate?

Comment: @bluefeet I don't think a threshold is required but it may be considered (I admit I'm member of some SE sites I don't visit often). because it may limit the problem they intended to workaround with a fixed list. If I have to pick a number I would say 150 (100 initial bonus + 50 of true activity).

Comment: We get plenty of requests to migrate stuff to sites that users have 101 rep on, but they have no clue what is on-topic and those requests are typically declined.  Without some sort of threshold for activity or rep, I can only see this as ending badly.

Comment: Yes, that's why some sort of threshold _may_ be appropriate (but I don't know SE facts enough to judge this). In any case for everyone else there are always comments to suggest a migration directly to OP.

Comment: IMO, I'd suggest including in your request some suggestions for a threshold.

Comment: @bluefeet tnx, I did. I can't imagine something more exact because I really don't know how much trouble you have with "wrong" migration requests (if this will increase number of wrong requests then it won't be a benefit for SE).

Comment: What if the threshold was 3K on both sites? If you can vote to decide what is on-topic, shouldn't you be able to decide if a migration is correct?

Comment: While it would add a bit of complexity, having each site be able to set a threshold of "how much rep you need to have here to migrate stuff to this site" would be rather nice.  If certain communities find that users with just a few hundred rep have typically learned what the site's scope is, they can set it low, if a site (say, I dunno, programmers) find that users even with a moderate amount of experience struggle to understand the site's scope they could set it to a higher amount.  It also lets you account for the fact that the age/size of the site affects the number of users above X rep.

Comment: @Servy well I didn't think about a variable threshold for each site but it may help a lot. TeX moderators may decide a 500 rep user is experienced enough to post a request when a SuperUser member needs to be at least 1000 (for example!!!)

Comment: Probably the most pivotal question for this feature request is do you require 5 migration votes from people with sufficient rep on the target site, or do you let one person with sufficient rep effectively add that site to the migration list for that question, allowing others without enough rep to rubber stamp it?  If you do the former then your odds of actually getting 4-5 close votes is very low.  If you do the latter then you're not adding nearly as much protection as may be needed.

Comment: There are lots of people who were 'active' on P.SE (for example) 3 years ago, but haven't been back since.  They occasionally suggest reposting on P.SE in comments and are most always wrong. I would dread seeing the results of if they could vote to migrate instead of just leaving incorrect comments.

Comment: Well there are stackexchanges that are unlikely to be a migration targets. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ for example. We should limit it to http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology and http://stackexchange.com/sites#science.

Comment: @MichaelT nice point. Together with what Servy and Trilarion said...that makes me think that probably migration be revisited little bit (I don't know stats but maybe it's not such common). If it's too easy then we (or target site) will get more _garbage_ but if it's too difficult then OP will have to wait too much for an answer. Well, yes, future readers will have advantages from such answers but OP may not have any benefit.

Comment: @Servy I agree there should be "something" to limit and control migrations (otherwise we just move _problems_ to another site), do you think a rule like the one applied for people with gold badge (to mark questions as dups) may work also here? 5 votes from _normal_ users OR 1/2 votes for gold badge users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an idea that is quite simple and might solve a lot of problems associated with migration.

The problem is that we may not have enough experts here to decide if a question is ontopic at another site. We cannot guarantee it. Therefore we need double voting by default.

In case of a possible migration we (without any regard of rep on other sites) can propose and vote on a potential migration towards any site in the technology and science section of SE, i.e. all these options are given at all times. The final option is the most often voted on.

Then if the vote was successful in a second step the target site gets to vote if they want to have the question.

If the second vote is negative the question gets closed as off-topic and not migratable. We did what we could then. It's primarily the duty of the questioner to find the right site, not ours.

The big advantage is that we don't have to be experts on other sites to know that a question is not for SO (we only make proposals where it might be located better) and the final migration decision is completely in the hands of the target site, so no complaints whatsoever.

Disadvantage is that the vote has to take place twice.

As a shortcut in case we have the experts of the target site than the two votes can also combined, i.e. the votes from the first vote with enough rep in the target site are automatically counted towards the second vote also.

Also there should be a time out, so if the second vote hasn't finished within a certain time the migration fails.

---

Example: I don't have to be a physics expert to know that a question asking for solving the many-body problem numerically is nothing for SO. So we redirect it the best way we can but if the target site doesn't want it.. well scrap it.

Comment: I like double voting idea (we have problems with "accepted edits" then it would be nice to avoid them for migration) but this may increase time (for OP) to get an answer. Other people will _enjoy_ late answers but OP won't have (probably) any benefit.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti But there isn't really an alternative. We cannot expect to have always enough experts from other sites to decide it's ontopic there and might get complaints about unwanted migration. The only real alternative is closure of the question here and reposting by questioner somewhere else. If the questioner post at the wrong site and does not have time to wait for a migration...

Comment: I understand that and honestly I think very few questions should be migrated (at least I voted to close as off-topic for that reason very few questions) so we may accept some spurious "false positive". I mean: double voting is OK (with a "timeout", if question isn't migrated in X days then it's simply closed as off-topic) but I'd also include a "shortcut" for experienced users (based on rep, badges or their "history").

Comment: @ArianoRepetti Why not. I like shortcuts. Just to understand you correctly. You mean experienced users can migrate their own questions automatically in case they missed the right site or you mean that experienced users can induce migration of a question without approval of the target site?

Comment: 2nd one. If, let's say, I have 1000 (or 10000, I can't give a threshold) rep here on SO then my vote is enough. If I ALSO have 1000 (or 10000) on Mathematica then migration is direct otherwise it has to be voted there too.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I like it and added this to my answer.

Comment: Yes, it may work like that! Devs have to manage another queue and rep threshold on "target" site may be lower (let's say 100 to accept but 1000 to propose + shortcuts for high rep users) but it may be a good way to manage that.