# What should I do when I think a question should be migrated to a site outside the proposed list?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

I occasionally see questions more fit for another site in the SE network and when I do, I always flag them for migration. Currently, we have a few options:

[image]

I understand [the reason why we have only 5 options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253998). However, some of the questions I would like to flag for migration are best fit for sites outside this list and I don't know what I am supposed to do:

1. **flag for moderator's attention**: this would work, but I'd rather avoid making the moderator flag queue even longer for no substantial reason.
2. **leave a comment asking the OP to delete and repost on the other SE site**: we risk having a duplicate post across the two sites and no way to detect it.
3. **close it with the same message as above**: we risk loosing good answers if it gets closed and the OP does not repost it on the other SE site.
4. **do nothing**: currently my choice, not a great one though.

What should I do?

Comment: If you think that the question is on-topic for another site and not SO, then use "Other" to flag for a moderator to act on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #1 is the correct option.

When it comes to migrating to sites that are not on the list, it is best to alert a moderator to this.

Moderators discuss such migrations with the moderators of the target site - what you may think is suitable, may not be (for example, Programmers gets quite a lot of migrations requests that are not suitable, people think that if it is off-topic on Stack Overflow, it is on topic for Programmers - if they are not actually active on Programmers, 9 out of 10 times they are wrong).

So - this is definitely something you want to let moderators handle.