# How should I flag my own question to have it migrated?

Tags: support, flags, migration

[Applied usermod and chmod but still no write access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65766743/12076263)
This is my own post.  I posted it on SO before I realized that it was a better fit for Unix/Linux Stack Exchange, and there was even an answer there.  However, I cannot flag my question as a duplicate since these are two different forums, and to flag it for transfer doesn't give Unix/Linux as one of the options.  Is there a way to do this, or should the post just be deleted?

Comment: Since it's your own question, and it's self-answered (with no other answers), and it's off-topic on SO, and doesn't need to be migrated, I don't see any issues with simply deleting it.

Comment: Relevant: [What should I do when I think a question should be migrated to a site outside the proposed list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266915/11682469)

Answer (score 4):

If it is your own post, and there is no content (e.g., high-quality existing answers) to preserve, then you can simply *delete* it from Stack Overflow and *re-post* on another site. (If you've already re-posted/cross-posted it on another site, then obviously you can just delete it from the original site.)

Otherwise, you will need to raise a custom moderator flag to request migration. By "custom moderator flag", I refer to the option labeled "in need of moderator attention", which gives you a textbox into which you can type a detailed description. In the description, be sure to explain that you are the author of the question, that it has received answers you wish to preserve, and that you would like to have it migrated to a specific other Stack Exchange site. Moderators can migrate a question to any other site in the Stack Exchange network.

**Note:** Only questions less than 60 days can be migrated, even by moderators. If your question is older than that, it cannot be migrated. There's no need to flag under these circumstances, and if you do so, your flag will almost certainly be declined with a message saying that moderators cannot migrate old questions.