# Should Ask Different be added to the list of question migration sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

Today I came across a question in the review queue that was asking about uploading a build to App Store Connect. The error the question was asking about seems to be entirely related to the upload process and not to any code in the app. I thought that this seemed like a better fit for Ask Different than for Stack Overflow, because on their [Tour page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour), under "Ask About," they have:

> Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)

But, under Community Specific -> Belongs on a Different Site, this wasn't one of the options. (I just Skipped that review instead.)

Is this a common enough migration target to merit inclusion on the dialog box? Right now it looks like this:
[image]

I'm aware of [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253998/why-are-only-five-migration-se-sites-offered-when-close-flagging-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1); this isn't a "why are there so few migration targets to choose from" question - instead it's about *whether this particular site* has enough overlap with non-programming-related iOS/Swift questions on Stack Overflow to be added to the dialog box. That's also why I've tagged this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) but not [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: For what it's worth, if we _did_ decide that another site should be in the list, Tex.SE could be pretty safely removed... it's used an order of magnitude less than the others.

Comment: I'm not sure what a non-programming-related Swift question would be.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also, tools primarily used by programmers are on-topic, so I'd expect questions about uploading builds to App Store Connect (in contrast with questions about App Store policy) to be generally on-topic here.

Comment: did you ask at their meta whether they want to become a migration target?

Comment: @RyanM A guess on how other questions similar to that one might have been tagged, if Swift had been used for the app but the question wasn't about the app's code. I don't know how many would be in that category as the question was prompted by this specific one from the screenshot. But, if they would be on topic here too, then it seems like a moot point, and **this** question (not OPs) is close-worthy

Comment: @gnat-onstrike- I'm not very familiar with the migration process, and didn't realize it was coordinated both ways, not just based on the question's topic.

Comment: I have voted to close this as *Opinion-Based*, since @RyanM has said questions like the one from the screenshot are actually on topic for Stack Overflow too.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck:  Wouldn't make sense to close this as opinion based, as there's a very, very objective answer to this question.

Comment: @Makoto Which reason would you suggest? "Resolved" isn't one of the choices

Comment: Not really related, but since this is an active question, has anyone else encountered the race case in the review queue? When you press "Submit," sometimes nothing happens for a very long time (usually, in this case, the button grays out and shows a "loading" animation on top of it, but *not always*). If in this situation one were to assume they had misclicked (or that the browser window hadn't been selected), and then **click Submit again**, the result would be the same review action being applied to the next **two** tasks *simultaneously*.

Comment: Of course, the hypothetical reviewer would have learned from their mistake and been careful not to double-click "Submit" in the future :D

Comment: sure this is about question topics, that's why I asked if you checked at their meta. Target site users are by definition best experts on this matter and it looks only natural to ask how they feel about letting ordinary SO users (who may have quite vague idea of target site scope) move questions to their site

Comment: ...and besides, this is a matter of [basic courtesy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399730/so-please-add-finally-more-sites-to-this-question-belongs-on-another-site-in-th#comment784586_399730) "I'm coming to a party at your house. What time should I turn up? I've invited all my friends too."

Comment: Whoa! I read it as *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For what it's worth, this *does* highlight why the migration workflow is heavily flawed.

A site like Stack Overflow is suitable for a lot of technical things that technical people do, including:

- Uploading applications to an app store
- Exceptions in doing such
- Problems with app code

A site like Ask Different is suitable for a lot of Apple-specific technical things that sometimes non-technical people do, similar to how Unix and Linux or Ask Ubuntu operate.  This means you'd see questions like:

- How to install applications
- How to add users
- How to work with specific applications

It's important to see that the person asking the question on Stack Overflow is doing so from a developer's perspective, not an end-user's perspective.  So...it'd be best served here.

Just to avoid things getting mixed up, it's best to think of it like this:

If you need to migrate it, it needs to be on-topic on the target site *and* have a higher likelihood that it will be answered on the other site.  Otherwise, leave it be.